# Show/hide markerclusters in Google Maps with Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, markerclusterer

I've got a map with 2 types of markers and until now I provided 2 checkboxes which gave the possibility to show/hide those markers with this code:

Checkboxes

```
<input type="checkbox" id="suggested" name="suggested" onclick="toggleMarkers('suggested')">
<label for="suggested"> Suggested</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="organized" name="organized" onclick="toggleMarkers('organized')">
<label for="organized"> Organized</label>
```

Javascript

```
function toggleMarkers(type) {
    switch(type)
    {
        case 'suggested':
            for (var i = 0; i < suggested.length; i++) {
                if (suggested[i].getMap() === null) {
                    suggested[i].setMap(map);
                } else {
                    suggested[i].setMap(null);
                }
            }
            break;

        case 'organized':
            for (var i = 0; i < organized.length; i++) {
                if (organized[i].getMap() === null) {
                    organized[i].setMap(map);
                } else {
                    organized[i].setMap(null);
                }
            }
            break;

        default: break;
    }
}
```

where `suggested` and `organized` are the 2 arrays containing the markers of the corresponding type. Now I've noticed that with many markers that is not enough and the map can be confusing, then I've decided to introduce the markercluster. I could do so, it was enough to import the library and to add

```
let suggestedCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, suggested, {gridSize:80, styles:styles[0]});

let organizedCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, organized, {gridSize:80, styles:styles[1]});
```

The problem is that I want to leave the functionality to show/hide a category of markers, but the code above is no more good for that, it has a wrong behaviour. How could I show/hide a category of clusters and also the markers of the same category which are not included inside a cluster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the reference](https://googlemaps.github.io/js-marker-clusterer/docs/reference.html), `MarkerClusterer` has methods `addMarkers` and `clearMarkers`.

```
function toggleClusterer(type){
    switch(type)
    {
        case 'suggested':
            toggle(suggestedCluster, suggested);
            break;

        case 'organized':
            toggle(organizedCluster, organized);
            break;
    }

    function toggle(clusterer, markers) {
        if(clusterer.getMarkers().length == 0){
            clusterer.addMarkers(markers);
        } else {
            clusterer.clearMarkers();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course now that I've introduced the markercluster I will not use simple markers anymore, that was just to explain the situation. I'll try do implement what you suggested.

Comment: Doing so, I get a `TypeError: this.ma.remove is not a function` message into the console refering to `clusterer.setMap(null);`

Comment: Almost there. Now the clusterer is removed from the map, but at the second click on the checkbox it doesn't show back. I've got this hint from my IDE `Invalid number of arguments, expected 1` for the instruction `clusterer.setMap(map, markers);` infact looking at the setMap function's signature, it accept only the map as parameter.

Comment: D'oh! Silly mistake.  That line should read `clusterer.setMarkers(markers);`

Comment: The function `setMarkers()` is not defined. I'm using the library v 1.0.3 for GMaps v3.

Comment: I'm hoping this is the last edit.  `setMarkers` should be `addMarkers`